# How to change url and get value without refreshing page?

Tags: php, codeigniter

controller: Welcome.php

```
public function tutorial_overview()
{
    $link = $_GET['link'];
    echo $link;
}
```

view: index.php

```
<?php
    foreach($heading as $sub)
    {
    echo "<li>
            <a href='javascript:void(0)' class='links' id='".str_replace(" ",'-',$sub)."'>
                <i class='fa fa-angle-double-right'></i>&nbsp;".$sub."
            </a>
        </li>";
    }
?>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".links").click(function(){
            link = this.id;
            history.pushState(null, null, '<?php echo base_url(); ?>'+link);
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>tutorial_overview/"+link,
                success:function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

In this code I have create a view file inside it I have define

```
<a href='javascript:void(0)' class='links' id='".str_replace(" ",'-',$sub)."'>
            <i class='fa fa-angle-double-right'></i>&nbsp;".$sub."
        </a>
```

which is dynamic. Now I want to change the url link as well as change the content that means when I click on link url will change and content will also change without refreshing page. So, How can I do this ?Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: I guess you need to take a look at AJAX

Comment: I am using pls see my code as well

Comment: I mean that you need to avoid using PHP in JS and just use AJAX/ JS

Comment: [RTFM](http://api.jquery.com) this isn't a free coding service

Answer (score 0):

I think your jQuery code has the problem -

```
link = this.id;
```

Try to apply code below -

```
$(".links").click(function(){
    var link = $(this).attr('id');
    var newUrl = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>' + link;

    history.pushState({}, null, newUrl);

    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>tutorial_overview/"+link,
        data: { link: link },
        success:function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

What you need to do is - Call ajax, get data and then do other stuff. You may change URL via history pushState when need. Be aware that older browser isn't compatible.

Comment: Now what happen when I click on link url change but inside controller I used echo GET value why its not working @HADI

Comment: @omkara please make sure you are passing data to ajax URL. The code I have given isn't passing data. just add `data: { link: link }` ** I have updated answer